# Error in replacing text in R

Tags: regex, r, replace, runtime-error

I m replacing one text in R using sub.

```
 x<-"My name is ${name}"
 sub("${name}","Tiger",x)
```

Error Message:

```
Error in sub("${name}", "Tiger", x) : 
  invalid regular expression '${name}', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
```

Input text has {}, How to fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `fixed=TRUE` argument:

```
sub("${name}","Tiger",x, fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "My name is Tiger"
```

Answer (score 7):

`$`, `{`, and `}` need to be escaped:

```
sub("\\$\\{name\\}","Tiger",x)
# [1] "My name is Tiger"
```

Comment: I was going to recommend you also look at the `gsubfn` package but a fresh install is giving me segfault issues... While researching the issue I found at least one user in the same situation. I am on a mac.

Comment: @G, if I am missing a required package or software, may I recommend that you throw an error or warning during install or during usage? Anything but a segfault that forces R to close...

Comment: It already checks for tcltk capability as well as for tcltk itself and substitutes R code if either is not found.  The problem may be due to problems with R itself or with the Mac build but I don't have a Mac to investigate further.